# How to listen for external android app events

Tags: android-studio, android-notifications, event-listener

Is it possible to set up a listener to external android apps?

For example: a custom app which can listen for Facebook messenger IMs and store the username of the user which sent the message?

Comment: Short answer: Hopefully not ... Long answer: Only of the original app is poorly written and even then not without the user acknowledging even once, that your app will receive the message.

Comment: What about listening for notifications, can you listen for just the notification by itself?

Comment: Again, hopefully not ... Just imagine things like 2FA will possibly break apart if any app can just read incoming notifications for any other app ...